# Rgeos breaks on centOS with error in GeometryComponentFilter.cpp:34

Tags: r, crash, centos, geos

I'm working on a remote machine.  Output from `uname -a` is:

> Linux some-server.some-place.com 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue
>   Mar 25 19:59:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm having trouble with the R package rgeos.  Here's a quick R session:

```
> library(rgeos)
rgeos version: 0.3-8, (SVN revision 460)
 GEOS runtime version: 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921 
 Polygon checking: TRUE 

> version_GEOS()
[1] "3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921"
> example(gDistance) 

gDstnc> pt1 = readWKT("POINT(0.5 0.5)")

gDstnc> pt2 = readWKT("POINT(2 2)")

gDstnc> p1 = readWKT("POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))")

gDstnc> p2 = readWKT("POLYGON((2 0,3 1,4 0,2 0))")

gDstnc> gDistance(pt1,pt2)
R: GeometryComponentFilter.cpp:34: virtual void geos::geom::GeometryComponentFilter::filter_ro(const geos::geom::Geometry*): Assertion `0' failed.

Process R exited abnormally with code 255 at Fri Feb 27 20:41:41 2015
```

What should I do to try and fix this?

Googling led me to http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/gDistance-problem-on-RHEL-6-64-bit-td7587736.html.  I tried some of the recommendations, including running `R -d gdb`, but that gave essentially the same output:

```
> p1 = readWKT("POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))")
> p2 = readWKT("POLYGON((2 0,3 1,4 0,2 0))")
> .Call("rgeos_distance", rgeos:::.RGEOS_HANDLE, p2, p1, c(FALSE, FALSE), 
+ 
   PACKAGE = "rgeos")
+ R: GeometryComponentFilter.cpp:34: virtual void geos::geom::GeometryComponentFilter::filter_ro(const geos::geom::Geometry*): Assertion `0' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000003b19c32925 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:  More info:

output from `lsb_release -a`:

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Release:    6.5
Codename:   Final
```

output from `rpm -qa | grep geos`:

```
geos-devel-3.4.2-1.rhel6.x86_64
geos-3.4.2-1.rhel6.x86_64
```

output from `rpm -qa | grep gdal`:

```
gdal-java-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64
gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64
gdal-python-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64
gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64
gdal-devel-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64
```

output from echo `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
/opt/tomlab/shared
```

output from which `geos-config`:

```
/usr/bin/geos-config
```

Comment: Looks like a GEOS bug (http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ticket/535) resolved in a version 3.4.3.

Comment: But it works for me with geos version 3.4.2-5.

Comment: @bergant and Pascal, how do I upgrade to a newer version of geos?  I don't own the server, so I'd have to explain to the owner how to do it.  Is there some new repo they'd have to add?

Comment: @Pascal is that the 2013/08/25  geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2 listed at http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ ?

Comment: It is provided by my distribution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CentOS, but have you tried installing GEOS as user, and either linking rgeos statically to it, or setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the dynamic library before running R and installing rgeos?

Comment: @EdzerPebesma No, I haven't, but how would I do that?  Adding some edits to the main question that might be relevant

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to statically link to it as  Edzer Pebesma suggests?